# Granular control with WIX IIS website installation

Tags: iis, wix

I am authoring an installer that creates a new website and application pool. This installer is for internal use within several development environments which all have subtle differences. One may use only HTTP, another only HTTPS and one might use both. One might use the default `ApplicationPoolIdentity` identity where as another may use an explicit `User` reference.

Given the association of a `WebAppPool` is by ID through a `WebApplication` which must be nested under a `WebSite`, each time an option is desired on the installer, the breakout and duplication of features gets ridiculous.

I imagine I am not the first to encounter this, how does one accomplish this much flexibility within an installer?

Answer (score 0):

The route I went with was creating a basic template within WIX using expected IDs, then used an immediate custom action scheduled before `InstallValidate` which manipulated the template entries to what ever degree was required. The properties used by the CA to make the decisions are stored in the registry for modify/patch/removal invocations.